# Using py2exe to make a windows exe, but it seems to have an issue with my script, - pandas\io\excel.pyc object has no attribute version

Tags: python, excel, pandas, py2exe, openpyxl

I am using `pandas` to create an excel file... my script works fine on pycharm and on the command line but as soon as I create an `exe` using `py2exe` and run that exe, it gives me this error:

```
File "TESTEXE.py", line 44, in <module>
   File "pandas\io\excel.pyc" line 570, in __new__
   File "pandas\io\excel.pyc", line 58, in get_writer
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I read a couple of places this specific error could be because some files may be named as `pandas.py` , but i checked the bundled folder that contains the exe does not have any such file

Line 44 in my script is basically
   `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)`

I know by default `ExcelWriter` uses `openpyxl` to create these files and i feel this is where the problem is. I changed the engine to 'xlsxwriter' and it was executing fine but it was messing up my target excel file (in other words, screwing with my logic)
another place that could be the culprit is the fact that when i ran the `py2exe` command, it did say `following modules appear to be missing` and a bunch of files were mentioned, could that be the case here?

I though i will also try PyInstaller, and i seemed to be getting the same error.

It could also be my setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas
import numpy
import os
import re
import time
import matplotlib


setup(
      version = "0.5.0",
      description = "py2exe sample script",
      name = "py2exe samples",

# targets to build
    options={
        "py2exe":
            {
                "includes": ["pandas", "numpy", "openpyxl" ],
                "excludes": [],
                "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll","HID.DLL", "w9xpopen.exe", "libzmq.pyd"]
            }},
            data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
console = ["TESTEXE.py"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be openpyxl stores its version string in a text file called .constants.json 
This does not get picked up by py2exe. This is in the main **init**.py file for openpyxl.

I did a quick hack to put the constants into the **init**.py file, but have not yet figured out how to correctly convince py2exe to add the file.

Comment: thanks, i tried to create an exe again, it seemed to have worked. I am guessing it had something to do with an older version of openpyxl/pandas